# Alternative to SSI in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssi

This has been asked before, and will be asked again!

I am currently building a small-ish corporate website (15-20 pages) in ASP.NET VB, I am NOT building it in visual studio, I am doing the layout in Dreamweaver CS5.5 and the code is in a hand edited CodeBehind .vb file per page. I am linking some bits of it to their internal Intranet, which I will build after the site. so its very minimally CMS'ed.
The site is not expected to get large amounts of hits, its more of a big brochure site for an engineering company.

I do not like Microsoft's hugely over complicated and un-fathomable MVC framework, and find their master page model restrictive and complex.

All I want to do is include the same code in my headers and footers on every page, people say that SSI is dead and the haters are angry people.

But really... whats a suitable substitute for that one little line of SSI include code?? its not big, its not clever, but its small and it works (that's my excuse anyway :-D ). I'm not building google! so server load isn't an issue, at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not like Microsoft's hugely over complicated and un-fathomable MVC framework, and find their master page model restrictive and complex.

Unsure why you have that **perception/assumption** (or how MVC equates to SSI)....based (only) on your post, it sounds like even Dreamweaver Library items or templates will suit your needs (haven't used DW in ages so if these are terribly outdated terms, they probably are).

Master pages can be as simple or complex as you want - they can simply give a header/body/footer paradigm or go deep with nested masterpages. You can have X number of master pages as well.

[If you must](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1652103/304683), you can use the "old school" `#include` just like you did in the distant past:

```
<body>
   <!-- #include file="~/static/staticHeader.txt" -->
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <!-- #include file="~/static/staticHeader2.txt" -->
```

And these will parse just fine (e.g. staticHeader2.txt):

```
<h1>This is included stuff 2</h1>
<p>The date is: <%= DateTime.UTCNow.ToString("u") %></p>
```

---

### Browser screen shot:

[image]

Comment: the problem i have is that if i start to use a "framework" the site then becomes locked into that, visual studio and DW start to "personalise" the code to their own needs, making it hard for future alteration and editing by a diferent developer. Hence why i want to use a simple import solution.

Comment: Still unsure what you mean about "locked" - in what way?...you probably just need more time to learn and/or familiarize with the tooling (Visual Studio) and the options provided by the framework.

Comment: what i mean is: if i did it in VS, then someone cones to try to edit it in a year or so, and doesnt have VS, they will probably find it very hard (have to assume the oroginal project is lost) I have come across this situation myself from the other side. Ive gone with a standard old include now, its simple, and works.

Comment: That's not true - all the *source files* (uncompiled) in your ASP.Net site can be edited in Notepad if you wanted to. "Projects/Solutions" are like grouping constructs in Visual Studio. I don't need VS to edit any asp.net/vb/cs source file in an ASP.net website/application. If I have VS, I can create my own "project" out of the collection of aspx/cs/vb files. As above, learn more about the tooling and the framework. Your comments are  perceptions / assumptions only.

Comment: i know that - however i recently had a situation where i had to do something like that, however VS completely broke it trying to create a new project. I do understand the tools, i simply wanted to know if there was a simple one-line import, like #include, that isnt looked down on by the haters.

Comment: AFAIK VS will not "break" anything (that's not already broken) - at least I haven't done it to myself (even if I edit the csproj/vbproj file directly). Perhaps it was just a case of missing dependencies - you can open the csproj or vbproj file in Notepad and it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: dont worry, as we both know, there is always a oddity in every new or "taken over" project, it will never be straight- forwards will it!!